# How do I assign different keys to each item in a list generated using itemBuilder in Flutter?

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've been designing an App where the User searches a term and a `GridView` is displayed containing all the images related to that term. All of these images are made `Draggable`.

In another `GridView` on the same page, I have placed 40 `Dragtargets`. So the user can Drag a searched up image and place it in one of the `DragTargets`, thus being able to select 40 images.

The issue is that when I drag one image to the `Dragtarget` grid, all 40 of the `dragtargets` are filled up with the same image. I think this is because every `Dragtarget` has the same key since it was generated in an itemBuilder. But i don't know how to set a different key to each `Dragtarget` while generating it. Would appreciate alternative solutions in implementing the same scenarios as well !

The code for Draggable Images:

```
                SliverGrid(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                      maxCrossAxisExtent: 350,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10),
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        child: LongPressDraggable<String>(
                          data: imageLinks[index],
                          feedback: Image(
                              image: NetworkImage(imageLinks[index])),
                          child: Image(
                              image: NetworkImage(imageLinks[index])),
                          onDragStarted: () {
                            panelController.close();
                          },
                        ),
                      );
```

The Code of GridView and DragTargets :

```
GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: 40,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 5,),
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5,right:5,bottom:5,left:5),
                    child: DragTarget<String>(
                    builder: (context, List<String> candidateData, rejectedData) {
                    if (dragged == true) {
                    return Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                    child: Image(
                    image: NetworkImage(draggedImage),
                    ),
                    );
                    } else {
                    return Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    );
                    }
                    },
                    onWillAccept: (data) {
                    return true;
                    },
                    onAccept: (data) {
                    setState(() {
                    dragged = true;
                    draggedImage = data;
                    //panelController.open();
                    });
                }
                  ),
                  );}
              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using single variable for all dragtarget elements.

Let Me Explain in code.

```
onAccept: (data) {
                    setState(() {
                    dragged = true;
                    draggedImage = data;
                    //panelController.open();
                    });
                }
```

In above code you set dragged value true and draggedImage value true, so every widget build with same value.

I hope i clear issue.

Solution:

To solve this issue, you can create a list of bool(if you want to keep that bool value different for all the dragtarget element also) and List of draggedImage while hold the draggedImage for each individual element, so all will not change when you change one.